# The problem with the compatibility of the Wi-Fi driver with Nvidia drivers and kernel 5.12 in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: networking, drivers, nvidia, kernel

Please help: I have a laptop Lenovo IdeaPad 5 Pro 16ACH6, it has a Wi-Fi module mediatek 7961, which does not work out of the box in Ubuntu 20.04, Googling a little found this article:
<https://zalinux.ru/?p=6346 >, after performing the operations indicated in it, I managed to get the Wi-fi to work, but my joy in this regard quickly ended because broken dependencies appeared in the form of problems with the libc6 version (version 2.33 is needed, and only 2.31 is installed), Googling for another 40 minutes found such a solution to this problem:

sudo apt-get install -f; sudo apt install --reinstall libc6=2.31-0ubuntu9.2; sudo apt install --reinstall libfakeroot

This solved the problem with dependencies, BUT in the process the kernel header package was removed, without which, as I realized a little later, Nvidia drivers that I need do not want to be installed normally. How do I still get a working Wi-Fi and Nvidia drivers?

Comment: 5.12 is not a kernel version supplied by the standard repos. Try either 5.11 or 5.13, and maybe avoid all the incompatibility issues.

Comment: @ubfan I was about to say the exact same thing! Great minds, I guess (I wish..) OP, how did you end up with 5.12 in the first place? It shouldn't upgrade via Apt unless you go explicitly looking for it. Did you need it per some dependency or something?

Comment: in the article, the link to which I gave in my question, it was said that the best work of WiFi is achieved with the 5.12 kernel, and since I'm new to linux, I just did what was written.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will try your advice